# Clojure: Qualified keyword inside a macro that resolves in caller's namespace?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

Is it possible to have a qualified keyword inside a macro resolve in the caller's namespace?  For example:

```
(ns a)
(defmacro m [] `(do ::k))
```

And in another namespace:

```
(ns b)
(use 'a)
(m)
```

In this example, `(m)` resolves to `:a/k` (the namespace where the macro is defined).  I am wondering if there is a way to get it to resolve to `:b/k` (the namespace where the macro is *called*).

Answer (score 5):

`(defmacro m [] (keyword (name (ns-name *ns*)) "k"))`